# MetroLog does not working after install appx file in windows phone 10

Tags: c#, logging, uwp, metrolog

I've install the MetroLog package from Nuget into UWP solution (VS2015).

In debug mode everything works fine - 
it create a log file in local folder and write contents inside.

When i create an .appx file, copy it into the WP device and install it, 
nothing happend, the MetroLog does not create any log file.

Please, need help?

Comment: MetroLog can be used in UWP apps. And I did a simple test as you've mentioned on my Lumia 640, it worked well. I can find the log file with Device Portal. How did you create your .appx package? And how did you check the log file in Windows Phone?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm creating the .appx file by right click on UWP solution and choose "Store" -> "Create App Packages" option.
I copy the .appx file into WP device and click on it.
I confirm installation the dialog and after that run the app.

Comment: Thank you Jay, I found the MetroLog file as you say with Device Portal.
the tool I'm working to see the local folder is "WP Power Tools" and by this tool i can't see the file (only in debug mode).

Again, thank you very much.

New issue that i found is in release mode with "Optimization code" checkbox is checked.
There is a white paper of do and not to do about Optimization code?

Comment: Generally speaking, "Optimization code" is only needed while building in Release mode. There is no much thing we need to do with "Optimization code". And my previous answer here might help you. Besides, if you have any new issue, it's better to ask a new question instead of adding a comment so that more people can see your question and give you better help. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MetroLog](https://github.com/onovotny/MetroLog) is supported in UWP. And by default, in will store logs in the app's **LocalState** folder. So the key point here is how to access **LocalState (LocalFolder)** folder in Windows 10 Mobile.

Usually, we may use some third party tools like [IsoStoreSpy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) or [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to access Isolated Storage. With these tools, we can access [LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx), [TemporaryFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder.aspx) and [RoamingFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder.aspx). However, these two tools can only works when the application is deployed in **Debug** mode.

For now, it is suggested to use **[App File Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal#app-file-explorer)** to view and manipulate files stored by your sideloaded apps. This tool should be able to work no matter your application is deployed in **Debug** mode or **Release** mode. But please note that this is a **new tool** added to [Windows Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal) in the **Anniversary Update**.

To use this feature, we need [enable Device discovery and Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile#turn-on-device-discovery-and-pairing). For more info, please see [Using the App File Explorer to see your app data](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/08/using-the-app-file-explorer-to-see-your-app-data/).